# Get year from boost ptime

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

I'm converting an existing program to C++ and here need to manipulate Sybase timestamps. These timestamps contain date and time info, which to my knowledge can be best handled by a `boost::posix_time::ptime` variable. In a few places in the code I need to get the year from the variable.

**My question is:** how can I most efficiently extract the **year** from a boost ptime variable? Below is a sample program in which it takes **three** lines of code, with the overhead of an extra `ostringstream` variable and a `boost::gregorian::date` variable.

According to boost documentation:

> Class ptime is dependent on `gregorian::date` for the interface to the
>   date portion of a time point

however `gregorian::date` doesn't seem to be a base class of `ptime`. Somehow I'm missing something here.

Isn't there an easier way to extract the year from the `ptime`?

Sample:

```
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   boost::posix_time::ptime t(boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time());
   boost::gregorian::date d = t.date();
   std::ostringstream os; os << d.year();
   std::cout << os.str() << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Skip the ostringstream.  Otherwise, you may benefit from "using namespace..."

```
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   using namespace boost::posix_time;
   std::cout << second_clock::local_time().date().year() << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```